# Use GDAL to convert DXF drawing to GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, dxf

Is GDAL capable of converting AutoCAD DXF to a GeoTIFF?

I've tried `ogr2ogr -f "GTiff"  C:/output.tif C:/input.dxf` and that returned `ERROR 1: GTiff driver has no vector capabilities`

`gdal_translate` doesn't seem to work either. I may be missing something obvious.

Basically, I have a DXF file which I want as a GeoTIFF to just load directly on a map as an image layer

Comment: have you tried gdal_rasterize ? - Just done a test in QGIS and it works ok

Comment: GeoTIFF is a raster format and ogr2ogr converts data between vector formats. You can see a list of supported formats with `ogrinfo --formats`.